# Static files don't get updated in django

Tags: python, django

Some static scripts and css in my django application fail to load and produce a "404" on both the terminal and the browser's console,

-I deleted the cache and refreshed million times

-I am very sure about the path to the files

-I have a static files directory defined inside every app; with a directory inside it carrying the app name "my_app/static/my_app"

-The settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join('static'), )
```

it consumed most of my day, what's the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `./manage.py collectstatic` and add this to your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
# ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: I'm running it locally

Comment: Thank you it works now. I disconnected the server, cleared the browser's cache, then added your code to "urls.py"

Answer (score 1):

Place the following in your `settings.py` file:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # based on where your settings file is, you might 
    # need to do "../static"
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```